# How do I get the result of a "SELECT" query and store it in a variable

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query in my code which looks like this

```
$edi_transaction_id = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT a.edi_transaction_id FROM edi_transaction_detail a JOIN reference_number b JOIN edi_transaction c WHERE a.asn_number = '$asn_number' AND a.edi_transaction_id = c.edi_transaction_id LIMIT 1");
```

I would like to get the value of that query and store it in $edi_transaction_id variable. I already thought this would run because it is working correctly when done on the mysql database directly but when I integrate it in my code this is the error

```
<b>Catchable fatal error</b>:  Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in <b>/home/ationgzon/WebService/edi_864_824_files.php</b> on line <b>53</b><br />
```

This is the line number 53 in edi_864_824_files.php

```
mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO `edi_864_824`(`edi_transaction_id`, `trading_partner`, `trans_date`, `issue`, `reference_number_id`) VALUES ($edi_transaction_id, '$trading_partner', '$trans_date', '$message', $reference_number_id)");
```

How do I do it so that I can insert it in my database.

Comment: `mysqli_query()` returns a mysqli_result object, not a string

Comment: Why is it so hard to [read the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)? It's all written there with examples!

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668624/how-to-display-mysql-select-statement-results-in-php

Comment: If you only need `edi_transaction_id` for the insert then, check out [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391344/insert-with-select) It shows how to `INSERT INTO` using the results of a `SELECT`

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
    $edi_transaction_id = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT a.edi_transaction_id FROM edi_transaction_detail a JOIN reference_number b JOIN edi_transaction c WHERE a.asn_number = '$asn_number' AND a.edi_transaction_id = c.edi_transaction_id LIMIT 1");
    while($row = $edi_transaction_id->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)){
    $edit_t_detail = $row[0];
    }
mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO `edi_864_824`(`$edit_t_detail`, `trading_partner`, `trans_date`, `issue`, `reference_number_id`) VALUES ($edi_transaction_id, '$trading_partner', '$trans_date', '$message', $reference_number_id)");
```

Here, `$edi_transaction_id` is the type  'mysqli_result object' so you cannot convert it to string

Answer (score -1):

Try to use mysqli_fetch_array instead, full documentation are available here : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: And when you read the documentation, you'll see you need a [result object](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php). As it stands, your answer doesn't fix the problem.